# How can I decide boundary for my object?

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where my player move from one place to another with key and i decide it's boundary with some numbers but I want to know that how can i decide an exact left point and right point which is equal to the camera's boundary.

So can anyone tell me that how can I do that?

My code is below :

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    if(transform.position.x > -2.7f){
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x-0.1f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        }
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    if(transform.position.x < 2.7f){
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x+0.1f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: No it's not attached with my player and its set on (0, 0, -10). 
[Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: Yeah I don't want to move my object outside of camera's boundary. When my player reach to the boundary it will stop at that point..[Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to restrict / limit player's movement, which is very commonly used. If **value** is smaller than **min**, it will return **min**, likewise with max value.

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x - 0.1f, -2.7f, 2.7f), 
                                                  transform.position.y, 
                                                  transform.position.z);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + 0.1f, -2.7f, 2.7f), 
                                                  transform.position.y, 
                                                  transform.position.z);
}
```

If applied, you can just remove your if statements.

**EDIT:**
Sorry I misunderstood what you meant. I see now you want to know how to set boundary if your camera size is changed dynamically. Is that right? In order to do that, you need to know the width and height of your camera. [This](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/174002/what-is-the-relationship-between-camera-size-units.html) has helped me conclude this formula:

The right side boundary of the camera is: `Camera.main.orthographicSize * Camera.main.aspect`
The top side boundary of the camera is: `Camera.main.orthographicSize`
The left and bottom side are just the negative numbers of them.

It seems that you don't need the top and bottom boundary, but I'll post it anyway.
So, combining with my previous answer, you can clamp your player position like this:

```
width = Camera.main.orthographicSize * Camera.main.aspect;

if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    posX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x - 0.1f, -width + (transform.localScale.x / 2), width - (transform.localScale.x / 2));
    transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    posX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + 0.1f, -width + (transform.localScale.x / 2), width - (transform.localScale.x / 2));
    transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Don't forget to consider about the object's scale itself. If you don't, half of the object will be able to move outside of the camera boundary.....

Comment: Yes I can use this for my project but if I create new project then I must have to decide what is the boundary point for my camera like in this project I have decided my camera's boundary is between -2.7f to 2.7f. But I want to know that is there any default method where Unity can decide its camera's boundary itself with code? [Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: Thanks Jay for help.Its working for me..[Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way to do this.
May be useful for someone.

```
    LeftPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).x + (transform.localScale.x * 5);
    RightPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0)).x - (transform.localScale.x * 5);
    UpPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3(0,0,0)).y + (transform.localScale.y * 5);
    DownPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0)).y - (transform.localScale.y * 5);


        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        if(transform.position.x > LeftPoint){
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x-0.1f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        if(transform.position.x < RightPoint){
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x+0.1f,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        if(transform.position.y < DownPoint){
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x,transform.position.y+0.1f,transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        if(transform.position.y > UpPoint){
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x,transform.position.y-0.1f,transform.position.z);
        }
    }
```